# How to replace IF statements for dictionary? (C#, Linq)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, if-statement

I have this equality comparer of a SampleObject:

```
    public bool Equals(SampleObject x, SampleObject y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return y == null;
        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!string.Equals(x.SomeId, y.SomeId))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (x.EventsList == null)
        {
            return y.EventsList == null;
        }

        if (y.EventsList == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e)
            .SequenceEqual(y.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e));
    }
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to replace all those IF clauses for a dictionary?

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: When x.EventsList and y.EventsList are both null, you treat them as equal - but when x and y are both null you treat them as unequal. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I don't think so: if (x == null) return y == null will return true, if x and y are both null. And Letie did not change the question, did she?

Comment: Do you definitely mean a dictionary? What would the key/value be for it? Or are you after some mechanism where you have some sort of enumerable set of rules and the first one to return terminates the enumeration of the rules?

Comment: Side note: please avoid `null` for *collections* like `EventList`; use empty one instead

Comment: @GWimpassinger Doh. :) Of course you're right. I need to increase my font size...

Comment: @LTV Is your goal to make the method shorter?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was asked in a code review instance to try and do this with a dictionary. But based from the answers here, it might not be the best approach. I think I might go with Dmitry's answer to get a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with a dictionary, but with a list. A dictionary has no order, hence you can't guarantee that your checks are performed in the right order. I used a list of tuples, where the first item is the condition, and the second item is the return value. Your code will be the following:

```
public bool Equals(SampleObject x, SampleObject y)
{
var checks = new List<(Func<bool>,Func<bool>)>
{
    (() => x == null, () => y == null),
    (() => y == null, () => false),
    (() => !string.Equals(x.SomeId, y.SomeId), () => false),
    (() => x.EventsList == null, () => y.EventsList == null),
    (() => y.EventsList == null, () => false)
};
foreach(var entry in checks)
{
     if(entry.Item1.Invoke())
     {
       return entry.Item2.Invoke();
     }
}
return x.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e)
            .SequenceEqual(y.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e));
}
```

But I strongly recommend to stay with your original version, because from my point of view the readability strongly decreases with this approach. Sometimes a classic sequence of if statements is much more appropriate then any fancy LINQ or whatever stuff.

Comment: I'll set this as the right answer since it does give the option for a "dispatch" solution. But I think, as @SomeBody suggested, that I'll try and go with the simpler descriptive way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I doubt if `Dictionary` is of any help here, but you can slightly simplify the routine into

```
public bool Equals(SampleObject x, SampleObject y) {
  if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    return true;
  else if (x == null || y == null)
    return false;

  // From now on, both x and y are not null

  //TODO: to avoid such constructions, do not let collections be null, but empty 
  if (x.EventList == null || y.EventList == null)
    return x.EventList == y.EventList;

  // From now on, both x.EventList and y.EventList are not null

  return string.Equals(x.SomeId, y.SomeId) &&
         x.EventList.OrderBy(e => e).SequenceEquals(y.EventList.OrderBy(e => e));
}
```

Comment: I like this! Looks clean and somehow less repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a dictionary is of any help here. You can replace all the if-statements by a simple expression:

```
return
    x == null && y == null ||
    x != null && y != null &&
    String.Equals(x.SomeId, y.SomeId) &&
    (x.EventsList == null && y.EventsList == null ||
     x.EventsList != null && y.EventsList != null &&
     x.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e)
        .SequenceEqual(y.EventsList.OrderBy(e => e));
```

Note that because of C#'s [short-circuit evaluation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/), the expression has to be evaluated only partially in most cases.